# nil guard with ActiveRecord maximum result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to return the maximum id or set to 1 with the following code Rails code (v3.2):

```
 b = PriceTier.maximum(:id) ||= 1
```

but get following error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting end-of-input
```

when there are no records. How would I get this to work? Does this work like a find where it is an exception (it doesn't appear to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second equal operator

```
 b = PriceTier.maximum(:id) || 1
```